# scripts/createChannel.sh: line 40: osnadmin: command not found Channel creation failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[image]

2021-11-03 00:38:38.401 +06 [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block

- res=0
  Creating channel mychannel
  Using organization 1
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=127
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=127
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=127
- osnadmin channel join --channelID mychannel --config-block ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --client-cert /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt --client-key /home/mkhan/hypfabric/abrar/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
- res=127
  scripts/createChannel.sh: line 40: osnadmin: command not found
  Channel creation failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`osnadmin` is a new command in Fabric v2.3. If you are on a prior version of Fabric, make sure to use fabric-samples from `release-2.2` branch instead of `main` branch.

Comment: Thanks  it worked after I installed Fabric 2.3